# Visualize Data as Color Bar in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a data visualization with pure JS. I can't find any examples of how to do this that don't rely on third-party libraries.

Let's say you have some data:

```
data = {
  green = 20%;
  yellow = 30%;
  red = 50%;
}
```

And you have created a rectangle in HTML that you can fill with color.

How can I use JS to fill the colors according to the percentage of each color? As you'll see in my code below, right now I've just hard-coded in the color percentages. But I want it to be dynamic so it updates when the data changes.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
const drawColors = () => {
  const colorBar = document.getElementById("color-bar");
  const context = colorBar.getContext('2d');

  // Hard coding percentages
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

  context.fillStyle = "yellow"
  context.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 100);

  context.fillStyle = "red"
  context.fillRect(200, 0, 100, 100);
}

drawColors();
```

```html
<canvas id="color-bar" width="300" height="100">
```

Comment: @ponury-kostek thanks for the edit, doing my best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you validate somewhere else that percentages values all add up to 100, iterate through the percentages object and fill like this:

```js
const percentages = {
  green: 50,
  yellow: 30,
  red: 20
}

const drawColors = () => {
  const colorBar = document.getElementById("color-bar")
  const context = colorBar.getContext('2d')
  //Calculate pixels from percentage based on canvas width.
  const toPixels = percentage => (percentage*colorBar.width)/100

  context.beginPath()
  let addedColors = 0 //To set the starting point of each fill.
  
  Object.keys(percentages).forEach(color => {
    let widthToPaint = toPixels(percentages[color])
    context.fillStyle = color
    context.fillRect(addedColors, 0, widthToPaint , 100)
    addedColors+= widthToPaint
  })
}

drawColors()
```

```html
<canvas id="color-bar" width="300" height="100">
```

Comment: This works so well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `createLinearGradient()` for this. Just converted 20% to 0.2 etc (sum has to be 1 or less);

```js
data = {
    green : 0.2,
    yellow : 0.3,
    red : 0.5
}

drawColorBar('canvas',data);

function drawColorBar(selector, data){
    const canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,0);
    let start = 0;
    for(const color in data){
        gradient.addColorStop(start, color);
        start += data[color];
        gradient.addColorStop(start, color);
    }
    
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Really cool solution - thanks so much.